# Feature to mark a favorite answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, bookmarks

Just like we get to mark questions as favorites, is there any scope/relevance of being able to mark individual answers as favorites as well. Of course, there is an indirect way to do that by 'upvoting' the answer and it will be recorded in the user profile's upvotes. But if we can mark favorite answers, it helps coming back later and referring to the concept (which supposedly has been explained in the answer).